# Configuring mod_rewrite issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have in my htaccess the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.py?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.py [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.py$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

First rule sends someone looking for

```
mydomain.com/<digits>
```

to mydomain.com/index.php?id=, second rule fixes hrefs inside index.py.
But when I add

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^0-9]+)$ index.py [L]
```

To make anyone whose request is not only digits go to index.py, divs in index.py just kinda disappear. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you're rewriting everything to `index.py`, including your style sheets or scripts or whatever. Try changing the rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^0-9]+)$ index.py [L]
```

Comment: Could you please explain me !-f and !-d?

Comment: @RomaValcer It checks that the request isn't for an existing file (`!-f`) and isn't for an existing directory (`!-d`).

Comment: So, we rewrite it only when you aren't looking for existing file, okay.